# Saving multiple changes to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using `.Net Core MVC` and for some reason, when I try to use a loop to save a bunch of files to the db at once I get this error:

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in
>   table 'Movie' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

From searching it seems this usually is generated when you try to manually set the Id but that is not what I am doing. Here is my code:

```
foreach (var item in files)
{
    string path = item.ToString();
    string title = path.Replace(remove[0] + remove[1], "");
    movie.IMDBId = 0123;
    movie.Title = title;
    movie.FilePath = path;
    movie.Year = "2007";
    _context.Add(movie);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

For some reason, this will save the first item in the directory and then gives me the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have searched for hours and haven't found a solution to this issue.

EDIT - Movie model

```
public class Movie
{      
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LibraryID")]
    public virtual Library Library { get; set; }
    public int IMDBId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string PosterPath { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the autoincrement to off?

Comment: Check the Movie Table Identity property, you set the property somewhere in the code, I would put my money to IMDBId =)

Comment: I didn't set the autoincrement to off, and as far as the imdbid I thought the same, so I even tried removing that from the statement. In the table it has Id as the Identity and I set it as [Key] in the model. I also tried adding [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] as well but that did not help either.

Comment: 1. The important technology here is EntityFramework Core, not ASP.NET Core
2. Could you show us your Movie object and the type behind _context? Your constraints, including primary key, are probably defined in one of these

Comment: I edited the main post.

Comment: You should create Movie class in yor for each loop. Each insert needs new reference. If you try same reference , entityframework gets confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** You should move your `movie` variable definition into local for-loop scope.

**Detailed answer:**

Since your variable `movie` is defined somewhere outside of your loop, it's reused for each file. The first time you run

```
_context.Add(movie);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

you create the object in the database and Entity Framework updates the object `movie`, setting the primary key and all other fields. Second time this code is run, EF tries to insert the object with the same primary key again, hence you get the error.

**Example solution:**

```
foreach (var item in files)
{
  string path = item.ToString();
  string title = path.Replace(remove[0] + remove[1], "");
  var newMovie = new Movie
  {
    IMDBId = 0123,
    Title = title,
    FilePath = path,
    Year = "2007"
  };
  _context.Add(newMovie);
  _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Good catch @Sergey, you might mention that setting the `Movie.Id = null` might also work, but it’s not a good practice for variable scopes.

Comment: I'd say it's also not a good practice in general, especially if the model class has some other auto-generated fields. It's easier and cleaner to just create a new model instance IMHO.

Comment: I kinda meant the same, to instanciate the movie just for the scope of saving it instead of reusing one instance

Comment: Strangeness to me, I have used this in a .Net MVC ( not core) app and it works great but this is my first run at a core app. I will give this a shot once im home in a bit, Thanks a million!

Comment: @user7704925, you  have to take same exception in a .Net MVC app. Then you save entity, EF return you saved instance with filled identity property. So, when you try to save this instance again in loop, you have already filled identity property.